# Sorting a csv given a key set python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that needs to be ordered with a specific order of names.

e.g the order key is

[David, Paul, Harry, John]

column1 of the csv is however :

- Harry
- David
- John
- Paul

And I need to order the csv so column1 is

- David
- Paul
- John
- Harry

How can I do this in pandas.

Comment: `sorted(rows,key=lambda row:order_key.index(row['name_index']))` ... I guess

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: Read the csv into a dictionary `d={row[1]: row}`. Then write a new csv with `for key in order_key: wrier.writerow(d[key])`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Categorical`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name=['Harry', 'David', 'John', 'Paul']))
df

    Name
0  Harry
1  David
2   John
3   Paul
```

Set categories

```
cats = ['David', 'Paul', 'Harry', 'John']

df.assign(Name=pd.Categorical(df.Name, cats, ordered=True)).sort_values('Name')

    Name
1  David
3   Paul
0  Harry
2   John
```

---

Without regard to the index and using `sorted` with a `key`

```
df.assign(Name=sorted(df.Name, key=dict(map(reversed, enumerate(cats))).get))

    Name
0  David
1   Paul
2  Harry
3   John
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the columns of names to the index and pass the list containing the order to `.loc` (data from @piRSquared)

```
ord = ['David', 'Paul', 'Harry', 'John']
df.set_index(df.Name).loc[ord,:].reset_index(drop=True)

    Name
0  David
1   Paul
2  Harry
3   John
```